# How do I update modules with security release only using composer?

Tags: 8, composer

On a Drupal 8 site, using the drupal-composer/drupal-project template, how would I go about updating only those modules which have a security release?

Our policy is to not update any module in our monthly maintenance routine unless it has a security update.

Ideally I'd like to find a solution which could be automated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I am using Drupal 7 modules as example, but just because there are more examples of security updates for Drupal 7 modules.)

Without custom coding, it's not possible. Drupal.org doesn't use a different name schema for security updates. From the version number you cannot know that [version 7.x-3.14 of the Views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views/releases/7.x-3.14) was a security update, while [version 7.x-3.13](https://www.drupal.org/project/views/releases/7.x-3.13) was not a security update.

That information is kept in https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/views/7.x, for the Drupal 7 version of the Views module, or in general in `https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/<project short name>/<Drupal version>`.
In the list of terms associated with a release, a *Release type* term whose value is *Security update* means the release is a security update.

```
<release>
  <name>views 7.x-3.14</name>
  <version>7.x-3.14</version>
  <tag>7.x-3.14</tag>
  <version_major>3</version_major>
  <version_patch>14</version_patch>
  <status>published</status>
  <release_link>
    https://www.drupal.org/project/views/releases/7.x-3.14
  </release_link>
  <download_link>
    https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.14.tar.gz
  </download_link>
  <date>1466019539</date>
  <mdhash>168bb684c8f34297be94b03c797841e5</mdhash>
  <filesize>1656594</filesize>
  <files>...</files>
  <terms>
    <term>
      <name>Release type</name>
      <value>Security update</value>
    </term>
    <term>
      <name>Release type</name>
      <value>Bug fixes</value>
    </term>
  </terms>
</release>
```

The classes under the [`\Drupal\update`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/namespace/Drupal%21update/8.2.x) namespace can help in writing the required code. [`UpdateProcessor::parseXml()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21update%21src%21UpdateProcessor.php/function/UpdateProcessor%3A%3AparseXml/8.2.x) is the method used to parse the XML data for a single project, but you would probably need to access one of the services Drupal implements.

Comment: Perfect, great answer. We'll be able to process the XML and figure out the release type. The option I had considered was using `drush ups --security-only` and then processing that output but this is cleaner.